# R convert character "111213" into proper time which is "11:12:13"

Tags: r, datetime-format, date-conversion

R convert character "111213" into time "11:12:13".

`strptime("111213", format="%H%m%s")` gives `NA`

and

`strptime("111213", "%H%m%s")` gives `1970-01-01 01:00:13 CET`

Comment: You need `strptime("111213", format="%H%M%S")`. And you can get a list of formatting parameters by checking `?strptime`. `%m` parse the month; `%M` parses the minute. `%S` parses the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the canonical answer would be as in my comment:

```
format(strptime("111213", format="%H%M%S"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "11:12:13"
```

where you can read `?strptime` for all the details. `format` is a generic function, and in this specific case we are using `format.POSIXlt`.

Another solution is to merely play with string:

```
paste(substring("111213", c(1,3,5), c(2,4,6)), collapse = ":")
#[1] "11:12:13"
```

This makes sense because your input is really not a Date-Time: there is no Date.

Comment: could you please update your solution with `91213` case ? current returns `NA`

Comment: @Qbik This does it: `format(strptime(sprintf("%06d", 91213), format="%H%M%S"), "%H:%M:%S")`. If your input is readily a string, make it an integer first: `format(strptime(sprintf("%06d", as.integer("91213")), format="%H%M%S"), "%H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 3):

We can use

```
library(chron)
times(gsub("(.{2})(?=\\d)", "\\1:", "111213", perl = TRUE))
#[1] 11:12:13
```

Answer (score 3):

To manipulate time, you can use [`hms`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hms/index.html) package.

By default, it working with `%H:%M;%S` (or `%X` format).

For you specifique time format (`"111213"`), you need to go through `base` function `as.difftime`

```r
hms::as.hms(as.difftime("111213", format = "%H%M%S"))
#> 11:12:13
```

Comment: What is class of output object ?

Comment: `hms` package works with *hms* objects wich are also of class *difftime*. 
The package creates " A simple class for storing time-of-day values" - it is its purpose

Answer (score 0):

So if we incorporate also date in similar "integer" format we can obtain command :

```
strptime("20181017 112233", format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
```